# RAD shows compile error while doing Clean All projects and Build Automatically

Tags: compiler-errors, rad

Often times when I open the RAD workspace and do a clean-->build all, then some projects show compile errors.
Now when I build each of the projects one by one, the error goes away. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when there are a 100 projects in the workspace and one project depends on another, and we do Clean-->Build Automatically for all projects, RAD messes up the order of the build. So it does not always build the dependent projects first. This gives compile errors for some projects because the dependent projects are not built first.

To solve this, we can do 'Build All' without the Clean option. This will ensure that the old files are still there and the dependent projects can reference the old files. This will remove the errors.